# Deleting file in Active@ Undelete

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card

I am using Active@ Undelete 9.5.59 to recover a folder that disappeared from my SD card.

After performing a scan on my SD card via Active@ Undelete, I've found the folder. But Active@ Undelete don't show the folder as a deleted one, It shows it as an available folder. I've recovered the folder successfully. Now, I want to delete it to free some space from my SD card. Unfortunately, there isn't a Delete button available in Active@ Undelete interface. I tried to *right click* on the folder in the Active@ Undelete and select *Open in Windows Explorer*. But nothing happens because the Winodws Explorer already doesn't see the folder.

Do you have any idea how to delete this folder using Active@ Undelete or any other software?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried wiping the free space on the drive?

Comment: If it's still occupying space on your flash drive (i.e. if all your files combined take about 1 GB and Drive Properties reports used space as 7.8 GB) then it probably means that the folder has the `SYSTEM` attribute set. To fix this, start a Command Prompt (Win+R -> "cmd" -> Enter) and enter the command `attrib -s -h -r /s /d h:`

Comment: After that command finishes executing (it could take a while), navigate to `H:` using Windows Explorer and you should see the folder that was previously not visible. You may then delete it. If the command fails, run `CMD` as Administrator and repeat. If it still fails and gives you a "Access Denied" error, you will need to [take](http://tipsandtricksforum.com/thread-223.html) [ownership](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404240.aspx) of the folder and all its subfolders and repeat the process.

Comment: @Ramhound No I haven't tried

Comment: @Vinayak The code gives me the "Access Denied" error. I checked the Ownership of the drive, and found that I'm already the Owner of the file. Also I'm running CMD as an administrator with the same result.

Comment: It'd help if you could add the output from that command to your question. To get the output in a text file so you can copy and paste it here, use this: `attrib -s -h -r /s /d h: > c:\output.txt`. Then open `c:\output.txt` and add the contents of the text file to your question.

Comment: The content of the resulted file is `Access denied - H:\System Volume Information`

Comment: Follow [this guide](http://techrena.net/take-ownership-grant-permission-file-folder-windows-7-vista/) **to the letter** and retry the command again.

Comment: Also check `Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object` in the third last step

Comment: Now the result is `Access denied - H:\System Volume Information\encstat.db

Access denied - H:\System Volume Information\IndexerVolumeGuid
`

Comment: @Vinayak What shall I do then?

Comment: Did you check `Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object`? If that didn't work, copy the contents of the flash drive to your computer and format it